# Files did not copy using shutil.copytree (Linux OS)

Tags: python, hard-drive, file-copying

I wrote a script to transfer my files from internal hard drive to an external disk. 
Code:

```
  import shutil
  from shutil import copyfile
  import glob
  import os
  from IPython import embed
  import subprocess

  path = os.getcwd()
  #pathHD = glob.glob(path+"/HD*")
  pathHD = glob.glob(path+"/RD*")

  destPath = "/mnt/backUp2/data/"

  for name in pathHD:
         #embed()
         baseName =os.path.basename(name)
         #Checking if directory exists in dest path
         if not (os.path.exists(destPath+baseName)):
                 print "Moving ",name,"--->",destPath
                 shutil.copytree(name,destPath+baseName) #recursive copying to destination dir

         else:
                 print name," *****************Already exists**********"
```

I copying was superslow, so I did a ctrl-c to stop the process. But now, in my external hard disk, I am not able to find the moved files at all. I do not understand how ctrl-C should stop it because each `shutil.copytree` command is independent of the other files.

```
My output:
Moving  /home/dhiraj/RD 4992Aug12 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4835Aug11 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4329Aug02 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4631Aug05 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4049Jul31 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4432Aug03 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4011Jul31 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4826Aug11 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
Moving  /home/raj/RD 4732Aug05 ---> /mnt/backUp2/data/
^C^C^C^C^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^X^X^X^X^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^C^C^C
[1]+  Stopped                 python copy_files.py
```

My filesystem is NTFS and I unmounted(lazy) using `sudo umount -l /dev/sdc2`. Whatever files that my output said, that it had moved, was not present in the destination file. Example, the first line of my output RD 4992Aug12 was notthere in my destination folder. I tested my script for a bunch of other files, which were also smaller in comparison and they worked fine. They were copies to my destination folder.

1. Please let me know if you can find why my copied files are missing
2. Should I use subprocess.Popen(cp) command instead?

NOTE:

1. I need to move files in TB, where each file is probably 0.5 GB.
2. My read speed of the disk 134Kb/s which is very slow.

Comment: To be honest, there are far too many confounding factors that make it hard for us to figure this out with any degree of certainty. What type of the file system does your external drive use? How did you unmount it? How did you look for those files to decide they were missing? If I were you, I'd try to reliably reproduce this with a single file, and then come back to us with a repro strategy that exhibits this behaviour. Then we might be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @NPE Thank you! I have updated my post, answering your questions.

Comment: Just to clarify, is "134Kb/s" how fast the disk says it can be read or is that how fast you're actually reading it? I ask because that number sounds incredibly low either way.

Comment: @supersam654 that speed is literally how fast my disk is reading it. Yeah, so  I am not sure if something is wrong with my disk.  On running a Defragler on it, my disk looked 20% fragmented. So I am defragmenting it right now. Note: My disk is a SSD.